# SCONS env.Library() does not get the expected environment compilation flags

Tags: scons

I'm running the following problem:
we have a large project (inherited from other company) compiling many sub-mules of SW.The contruction of the FW is sub-divided in several SConscripts
that we invoke from the main SConstruct. The point is that all the submodules share the same compilation flags and
defines.

I intended to solve this with the following solution:

In the main entry point , the SConstruct we define certain compilation options :

COMPILER_FLAGS      =    '-g \
                          -O3 \
                          -fshort-double \
                          -gdwarf-2 \
                          -Wall \
                          -W \
                          -Werror-implicit-function-declaration \
                          -Wno-unused-variable \
                          -Wno-empty-body \
                          -Wbad-function-cast \
                          -Wstrict-prototypes \
                          -Wmissing-noreturn \
                          -Wnested-externs \
                          -fno-builtin \
                          -Wno-unused-parameter \
                          -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast \
              ..........

This COMPILER_FLAGS are present the Construction environment which is passed to each Sconscript as argument
Then inside each Sconscript I make a clone of the environment and modify some of the options for each submodule

*SConstruct

```
log_path    = os.path.join('../../CDD/LogPrint/Build/logprint.SC')
objects += SConscript(log_path, exports='env', variant_dir=log_build_dir, duplicate=1)
dbg_exe     = env.Program(dbg_path, objects)
```

*logprint.SC

```
\#Customize Compilation options for this component
own_env = env.Clone()
own_env['COMPILER_FLAGS'] += '-O0 '

\# COMPILE SOURCE FILES
objects += own_env.Library(sources)

\# RETURN                     
Return('objects')
```

The point is that when I compile (and build a Library) for the logprint submodule I don't see the own_env extended
compiled Flags. I still see in the compilation command line printed the initial env options inherited from the main SConstruct file.

Any reason why this may be happening? Is there any top level SCONS option/configuration setting this behaviour? 
Let me also highlight that I probed this concept of env.Clone in a new small project from the scratch and there it
works. So I wonder is some top SCONS configuration might be blocking the own_env.Library behaviour I want in the 'large'
project.

Comment: You can use `print env.Dump()` and `print own_env.Dump()` before and after the assignment to `$COMPILER_FLAGS` to check whether the assignment correctly works. But even if `$COMPILER_FLAGS` is setup correctly, if we're talking about compiling C or C++ sources those flags won't be picked up during compiling. You have to stick to standard *SCons* conventions and use `$CCFLAGS` or `$CXXFLAGS` instead. Please check the [SCons UserGuide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) for more infos, especially the Appendix A where all the standard construction variables are listed.

Comment: COMPILER_FLAGS has no affect on any default builder.  Also your example code is incomplete. Can you flesh out your SConstruct and SConscript such that we can try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what I believe you're trying to do.

SConstruct

```
env=Environment()
env['CCFLAGS'] ='-g -O3 -fshort-double -gdwarf-2 -Wall -W -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-empty-body -Wbad-function-cast -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-noreturn  -Wnested-externs -fno-builtin -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast'
log_path = os.path.join('../../CDD/LogPrint/Build/logprint.SC')
objects = SConscript(log_path, exports='env', variant_dir=log_build_dir, duplicate=1)
dbg_exe = env.Program(dbg_path, objects)
```

SConscript

```
#Customize Compilation options for this component
own_env = env.Clone()
own_env.Append('CCFLAGS' = '-O0 ')

# COMPILE SOURCE FILES
objects = own_env.Library(sources)

# RETURN                     
Return('objects')
```

Comment: You want `own_env.Append(CCFLAGS='-O0')`! ;)

Comment: Yes effectively using the CCFLAGS instead of the COMPILER_FLAGS variable solved the issue.

Comment: @AlbertoRiera Great! Please mark this answer as the solution?